# How do you update some data stored in MongoDB but only after is validated by someone?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am making a React app with Nodejs in the backend with Mongoose/MongoDB. I have some data that I would like the user to be able to update. Let´s say for example, a Wikipedia article. However, when the user submits the update, I want to keep showing the old data until the new data has been verified.

Does MongoDB have some mechanism to help with this situation? Or do I have to make the whole mechanism? Kind of having two schemas, "DataSchema" and "DataSchemaProposal", then the user would submit a DataSchemaProposal and somehow implement the mechanism to replace DataSchema data with the proposal when the proposal is accepted.